# How do c++ communicate with python?

Tags: python, c++

By now I am using boost python to communicate with python and c++(call python library from c++), so far so good.But I don't understand how to setting the way of the exe looking for the python?

Like dll or lib, you have to write a makefile to show the compiler and linker what do you need, and setup the proper environment variable to help the exe find them(keep the libs and include folder only).But in the world of python and c++, I **do not setup any environment variable(or I missed it)**, I only do static link to the libboost_python-vc90-mt-s-1_55.lib and the python27.lib.

I tried to remove or place the python27 folder in another place, then the program can not run properly.
How could the program know where to find the folder they need?How could I change the default setting(like setting the default search directory )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are linking to the `python.lib` which contains the python virtual machine and interpreter, the JIT and the run-time environment. That's how C++ is communicating with `python`, you have embedded the full python interpreter into your C++ application.

Comment: maybe that could be explained in slightly more words by saying that python.lib is the program that supports the python virtual machine, its capable of compiling, and JIT-ing, so the python "engine" becomes a full part of the final C++ executable thanks to the content of python.lib.

Comment: I know why it can't work after I changed the position of python27, because the c++ exe need to find the "python27/Lib" folder at runtime.How could I reset the default loading place at runtime

Comment: The Python interpreter embedded in your .exe still needs to access some DLLs (just as the PYTHON.EXE executable does).